# A Fibonacci problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove this, can you provide me with some hint or something?
consider this equation:
$$
\prod_{i\geq 2 }^{\infty}(1-t^{F_i}) = 1 - t - t^2 + t^4 + t^7 +\dotsb
$$

I want to prove that the coefficients of the terms in this equality, are either $0$, $1$ or $-1$.

($F_i$ is the $i$-th Fibonacci number.)

Comment: In how many ways can an integer be written as a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers (paying attention to parities).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't understand...

Comment: When you multiply out the product, $t^n$ appears the same number of times that $n$ can be written as a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers.  Some numbers can be written in terms of Fibonacci numbers in multiple ways; the sign of $t^n$ depends on the number of Fibonacci numbers in the sum.  You will have some cancellation that you will need to keep track of.